# How to set page number in subreport of active report

Tags: report

I have created a report using Active reports.
But the problem I am facing now is to set the page numbers correctly.
The design of my report is as foloows:
1.The main report contains one sub report.
2.Inside this subreport I have two more sub reports.
3. Inside one of the sub report I have the detail design of my requirement.
As the entire report design is inside a sub report, I am not getting page numbers, coz we can not set page numbers in sub reports.
But I need it anyway.So please help me to get the page numbers.

My requirement is:
If 3 records are displayed in the report, then for each record the page number should be reset.That means, if each record covers 5 pages.
Then for each record, the page numbering should be like 1 0f 5.

How can I acheive it, if anyone has any suggestion.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set page numbers in a subreport ,but they will not be rendered correctly as subreports are not page aware .You may try merging the subreport with the main report to get correct page numbers on subreports

For merging you can refer to this article
http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/arHOWInsertOrAddPages.html